# Android 7.1.2 adb fails no permissions on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, adb

i have recently updated my phone to android 7.1.2 with lineage os 14.1,
now whenever i try to access adb i get

```
????????????    no permissions
```

what is the reason?
i have tried revokeing the RSA's for adb debugging on my phone
im Using ubuntu 17.04 with android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on developer settings in your phone. After updates sometimes it turns off. Also turn on USB Debugging mode and apk installation from unknown sources.